# Execute python script from everywhere

Tags: python, linux, bash

I would like to add some python script to path.

I can add bash scripts to folders in my path and then execute them from everywhere. 
When I do so with python script, I can only execute them when I am in the same directory.

Per exemple, if I put test and test2.py in the same folder in my path.

This work:

> ```
> sh test
> success hello world
> ```

This doesn't:

> ```
> python test.2.py
> python: can't open file 'test2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the python source file is in a directory that is on your path do the following:

1. Add this line to the top of your python file: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Set your python file to be executable: `chmod +x test.2.py`
3. Run your python script with: `test.2.py`

Comment: I'm inside a virtualenv. I have to call `./test.2.py`

Answer (score 4):

The `python` command doesn't search `$PATH` for scripts, like `bash` does.

Make `test.2.py` executable, and make the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then run it by typing:

```
test.2.py
```